# capture image from camera and show in fragment, restarting FragmnetActivity onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to capture image from camera and show it in a imageView in fragment, I have done the job, it is working fine on Motorola droid maxx XT-1080m kitkat 4.4.4
but restarting the faragmentActivity on galaxy s4 lollipop 5.0
this is my code

Intent for camera

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

onResultActivity()

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv_parse_user_profile_picture.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing on glaxy S4?

Comment: open camera> take picture> but when click on save button it close the fragment and restart the activity

Comment: @numanghuffar did you find a solution for this?

Comment: did you got the solution